# Is it possible to overwrite class attributes using web.config in C#?

Tags: c#, attributes, overwrite

I have a class that is decorated with a custom attribute derived from System.Attribute.

I want to change one property of this attribute.
Is it possible without modifying the code? Web.config maybe?

Comment: No it is not, you have to change the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't refer to your WebConfig from your **compiled** code, you won't be able to change the **compiled** Code later via WebConfig.

I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
var name = Settings.Default.Name;
```

You can change this value later in your app/web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <!-- ... -->
        <setting name="Name" serializeAs="String">
            <value>Robert</value>
        </setting>
    <!-- ... -->
</configuration>
```